# Openslyers import error in Angular component

Tags: angular, openlayers, openlayers-6

I have installed openlayers to my angular 12 project.

```
npm install ol
```

and

```
npm install --save @types/ol
```

But when I import in home component:

```
  import Map from 'ol/Map';
```

throws exception:

```
Error: node_modules/ol/ImageBase.d.ts:32:48 - error TS2694: 
 Namespace '"C:/Dev/my-app/node_modules/ol/ImageState"' has no exported 
member 'default'.

 protected state: import("./ImageState.js").default;     
 protected state: import("./TileState.js").default;
 protected layout: import("./GeometryLayout.js").default;
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is updating `tsconfig.json`.

In `tsconfig.json` file at the `compilerOptions` object add `"skipLibCheck": true`.

This will resolve the issue.